# How to prove if it is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be an open bounded set and $(v_n)_n\subset W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$ with $p>2$. Is this function
\begin{align}
\frac{\Vert v_n(x)\Vert_p^p}{1 + \Vert v_n(x)\Vert_p}
\end{align}
bounded?
I think it is true because the norms are finite since $(v_n)_n \subset W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$, but i would like to be sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any non-zero function $v$ in $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and take $v_n=nv$. Then $\frac {\|v_n\|_p^{p}} {1+\|v_n\|_p}\to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

[For any positive number $a$ we have $\frac {n^{p}a^{p}} {1+na} \to \infty$ because $p >2$. (In fact $p>1$ would suffice)].

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, if I consider the function $\frac{\Vert v_n\Vert_p^p}{1 + \Vert v_n\Vert_p^p}$, I can say that it is bounded, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, just another thing: roughly speaking, I can say that $(v_n)_n\subset W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$ means that $(v_n)_n\subset L^{p}(\Omega)$ and $ (\nabla v_n)_n\subset L^p(\Omega)$?

Comment: @C.Bishop $0 \leq \frac A {1+A} \leq 1$.